# I have unknown error in console in my react application

Tags: reactjs

What does it mean?

Error in event handler for (unknown):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined
>       at t.runtime.sendMessage.e (chrome-extension://mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij/dist/content_script_bundle.js:1:22694)

Comment: hey, please share that snippet of code where you reading/accessing `response`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome extension with id `mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij` seems to be ghostery. You probably should disable it for local development.

Comment: yes, it's realy because of the ghostery. I switched it of and error disappeared . Thank you )